# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x621a1f147f921) in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, struct, crash, exc-bad-access

Please find the code below

```
class TaskAssigneeTableViewCell: GroupCell {

struct TaskShiftTime {

    var assigneeID: String?
    var userID: String?
    var taskStartTime: Date?
    var taskStopTime: Date?
    var userShiftStartTime: Date?
    var userShiftStopTime: Date?

    static func convertToShortDate(date: Date?) -> Date? {
        guard let date = date else { return nil }
        return DateUtil.convertDateToDate(date, format: APP.CONSTANTS.TIME_FORMAT.USER_SHIFT_TIME)
    }

}

fileprivate var taskShiftTime = TaskShiftTime()
fileprivate var shiftTimeIsBeingEnabled = false

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

@objc convenience init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?, taskID: String, assigneeID: String, userID: String) {
    self.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    configure(taskID: taskID, assigneeID: assigneeID, userID: userID)
}
```

}

```
extension TaskAssigneeTableViewCell {


fileprivate func configure(taskID: String, assigneeID: String, userID: String) {
    taskShiftTime.assigneeID = assigneeID // the app crashes here giving exc_bad_access
    taskShiftTime.userID = userID
    setTaskTime(task: taskID)
    setUserShiftTime(user: userID)
}
```

The code that creates the cell is as follows -

```
        (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GroupCell";
        NSDictionary * dic;
        dic = [self.MembersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *idUidString=@"";

        // EVO - SWIFT
        GroupCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


   if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TaskAssigneeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier taskID:self.TaskId assigneeID:self.assgineeUid userID:[dic valueForKey:@"uid"]];
    }
return cell;
}
```

the code works fine for iOS 12 but crashes in iOS 13. 
I am uanble to understand that why it gives me bad access exception as taskShiftTime is already created before accessing its properties.
From my knowledge, bad access exception usually occurs when we are trying to access something that has been deallocated but that doesnt happen in my case. I am failing to understand this.

The crash log from fabric.io is as below -

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b6a0c7b4 _swift_release_(swift::HeapObject*) + 40
1  AirportTalk                    0x1051e2fdc specialized TaskAssigneeTableViewCell.configure(taskID:assigneeID:userID:) + 52 (TaskAssigneeView.swift:52)
2  AirportTalk                    0x1051e0804 @objc TaskAssigneeTableViewCell.init(style:reuseIdentifier:taskID:assigneeID:userID:) (<compiler-generated>)
3  AirportTalk                    0x104f23ff4 -[SelectAssignee tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 142 (SelectAssignee.m:142)
4  UIKitCore                      0x1ad76bc88 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 640
5  UIKitCore                      0x1ad739348 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2608
6  UIKitCore                      0x1ad756510 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 160
7  UIKitCore                      0x1ada1b604 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140
8  QuartzCore                     0x1aff6978c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
9  QuartzCore                     0x1aff6f908 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480
10 UIKitCore                      0x1ada078b8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 536
11 UIKitCore                      0x1ace9f7dc -[_UISheetPresentationController _sheetLayoutInfoLayout:] + 48
12 UIKitCore                      0x1ace9d110 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _layout] + 312
13 UIKitCore                      0x1acea15a4 __54-[_UISheetPresentationController transitionWillBegin:]_block_invoke_2 + 52
14 UIKitCore                      0x1ada0e09c +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 96
15 UIKitCore                      0x1acea14d8 __54-[_UISheetPresentationController transitionWillBegin:]_block_invoke.337 + 128
16 UIKitCore                      0x1acf98a28 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 264
17 UIKitCore                      0x1acf953d8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations] + 256
18 UIKitCore                      0x1ada0de6c __63+[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:]_block_invoke + 28
19 UIKitCore                      0x1ad9e2a00 -[UIViewAnimationState _runAlongsideAnimations] + 32
20 UIKitCore                      0x1ad9e18ac -[UIViewAnimationState pop] + 52
21 UIKitCore                      0x1ad9deff0 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 64
22 UIKitCore                      0x1ada0f7b8 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 648
23 UIKitCore                      0x1ada0fd44 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 108
24 UIKitCore                      0x1ad9da870 __50-[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:]_block_invoke.169 + 76
25 UIKitCore                      0x1ada10308 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) conditionallyAnimate:withAnimation:layout:completion:] + 88
26 UIKitCore                      0x1ad9da490 -[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:] + 616
27 UIKitCore                      0x1ad9d9f2c -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 2368
28 UIKitCore                      0x1acf91a38 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 1484
29 UIKitCore                      0x1acf99648 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 + 56
30 UIKitCore                      0x1ad0a70ac +[UIInputResponderController _pinInputViewsForInputResponderController:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] + 104
31 UIKitCore                      0x1acf995d8 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.645 + 176
32 UIKitCore                      0x1ada0dd54 +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] + 172
33 UIKitCore                      0x1acf99440 _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition + 580
34 UIKitCore                      0x1ace90a24 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.465 + 2348
35 UIKitCore                      0x1ad58fe7c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 316
36 UIKitCore                      0x1ad57f82c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 232
37 UIKitCore                      0x1ad5af8dc _afterCACommitHandler + 76
38 CoreFoundation                 0x1a949ac2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
39 CoreFoundation                 0x1a9495b18 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
40 CoreFoundation                 0x1a94960e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
41 CoreFoundation                 0x1a94958a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
42 GraphicsServices               0x1b33ed328 GSEventRunModal + 104
43 UIKitCore                      0x1ad586740 UIApplicationMain + 1936
44 AirportTalk                    0x105074aec main + 14 (main.m:14)
45 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a9320360 start + 4
```

Comment: It crashes on taskShiftTime.assigneeID = assigneeID in the configure method in extension TaskAssigneeTableViewCelll

Comment: Please show the code that creates the cell. Where do your cells come from? — Also please show the crash log so we can see how `configure` is being called. — Also I don't understand why `configure` is in an extension...? What's the point of that?

Comment: @matt Please find the updated description.

Comment: @matt I have also attached the crash logs from fabric. Please suggest why is it crashing only on iOS 13.

Comment: You're definitely having an ARC memory management issue and it seems to have something to do with the cross-language communication (your `cellForRowAt` is in Objective-C but the cell code is in Swift. But I can't interpret it further. It looks like this code is at the end of a presentation? Maybe the fact that iOS 13 presentations work differently has something to do with it.

Comment: Is there something else that you require at my end to dig in more? I am failing to understand this behavior. How presentations in iOS 13 work different than in iOS 12? Do you have any reference documentation?

Comment: “Is there something else that you require at my end to dig in more?” An MCVE project would help, obviously.

Comment: I have provided enough information I believe.